# Installing Kali Repositories

Tags: kali-linux, debian

Can I install Kali Linux repositories on Debian 9 Stretch. The last time I did this, my installation breaked after an update or installation of wine I think. The apt package manager was also not working. When I booted it loaded a tty1 terminal like interface. I also read a few things about debian not being compatible with other distro repos. However I see many people install Kali repos using Katoolin.
So the overall question is should I install Kali repositories?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kali is a Linux distribution and is not a security tool.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, though it is not adviseable.

Kali is based off Debian which makes tge repository at least compatible with grabbing and deploying packages. However, both distros follow different approaches - as Kali is a rolling release model (entailing that it receives constant updates and upgrades, e.g. currently 2018.4) it can be installed once and kept up to date by constantly running apt update/full-upgrade. 
Debian works a bit differently than that, you have to manually change the repos is order to upgrade e.g. to the next version.

Kali’s focus is to provide you the newest and bleeding edge security tools, Debian’s focus is rather on stability and ensuring dependancies are met when it comes to the orchestration of the entire system.

My personal advice, run Kali in a VM or rather on aRaspberry Pi (my own setup). That’s still enough contingency in order to play around with or do what you normally would like doing with it.